# AWS S3 object life cycle

Tags: amazon-s3, lifecycle

I want to delete object in S3 bucket in bulk after certain period is over. For example all object starting with 2016-08-01* in its name or *.xlsx files in a bucket. I can set life cycle for individual object not in * mode. How to do it?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Have you read through the documentation?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

According to S3 API you can [list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) objects that start with a certain `prefix` and then you can do a [multiple delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html).